# DELETE mysql not working over ajax?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have this query...

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['deletePost'])) {
$q = $dbc -> prepare("DELETE FROM boardposts WHERE postID = ? AND parentID = ?");
$q -> execute(array($_REQUEST['deletePost'], $_REQUEST['deletePost']));
}
```

The request I make from my js is called `deletePost` and the id which is carried along with it is correct.

Why might this fail like it is doing?

My js looks like so

```
$('.deletePost').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            deletePost: id
        },
        success: function() {
            $('.content').empty().html('<p>The selected post and all of its children have been deleted.</p>');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

It returns the success call and all other ajax on my site works fine. The settings for ajax are defined elsewhere.

Comment: Why are you passing the same value to `postID` and `parentID`?

Comment: Because that is what I need to do!

Comment: Why don't you care to execute your query on MySql at least once with appropriate data to make sure that at least your query is working fine?

Comment: Never thought of doing that will next time thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your query looks wrong. Shouldn't that be `WHERE postID = ? OR parentID = ?`?